# filtering options based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

I was creating an Airbnb clone where i give the user 3 filtering options

1. arrange the price from low to high
2. couple friendly stays
3. pet friendly stays

the individual code/logic works perfectly that is if I click on low-high it does arrange it from low to high. if I click on couple friendly and from the dropdown choose a "yes" it does give me the couple friendly options and vice versa if I choose "no" it even gives back the original data and the same works perfectly when choosing pet-friendly options depending on yes or no

the problem arises when let's say I choose "yes" from couple-friendly options AND THEN click on arrange them from low to high now the code breaks and  INSTEAD OF ARRANGING THE "COUPLE FRIENDLY" OPTIONS FROM LOW TO HIGH it starts arranging all the stays from low to high.

and the same happens when I first click on pet friendly and then click on arrange low to high the app again breaks and arranges all the data instead of only THE PET FRIENDLY OPTIONS.

HENCE INDIVIDUALLY IF I FIRST CLICK ON "YES" AND THEN "NO" AND FINALLY CLICK ON ARRANGE FROM LOW TO HIGH IT AGAIN STARTS WORKING BUT WITHOUT THAT IT DOESN'T can somebody please help me with this

the code

```
import React from 'react'
import "../styles/SearchDataPage.css"
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { placesStore } from '../store/Store';
import { useState } from 'react';
import filterbtn from "../styles/filterBtn.png"
import { MdOutlinePets } from "react-icons/md"
import { AiFillStar } from "react-icons/ai"
import { TiTick } from "react-icons/ti";



const SearchDetails = () => {


    const [openFilter, setOpenFilter] = useState(false); // toggle the filter dropdowm

    const [openPets, setOpenPets] = useState(false);   // topggle the pets dropdown
    const [petReviewes, setPetReviews] = useState(false);  // num of reviewes for pets

    const [coupleToggle, setCoupleToggle] = useState(false);  // toggle the couple button
    const [co, setCo] = useState(false);




    const params = useParams();
    const { loc } = params;

    var placeDetailsArray = placesStore.filter((item) => item.location.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(loc.toLocaleLowerCase()));  // getting the details from the main array with filter and storing it in "placeDetailsArray" and then passing it on to "orignalArray" state

    const [orignalArray, setOriginalArray] = useState(placeDetailsArray);


    const reviewesArr = ["Light cosy room in a modern home. Cosy clean light room with single bed and Wi-Fi, Furniture in this room will be update to higher standards by the time of your stay.",
        "Bright airy Studio apartment located on the Ground floor, a beautiful self-contained garden studio, located in the heart of historic Highgate Village.",
        "The apartment is equipped with a double bed and a double sofa bed and can comfortably accommodate 2 adults."
        , "The room has been newly decorated, Plenty of space for luggage, desk space for work. moreover the staff was very coopervative and helped us throughout the stay",
        "Light cosy room in a modern home. Cosy clean light room with single bed and Wi-Fi, Furniture in this room will be update to higher standards by the time of your stay.",
        "Bright airy Studio apartment located on the Ground floor, a beautiful self-contained garden studio, located in the heart of historic Highgate Village.",
        "The apartment is equipped with a double bed and a double sofa bed and can comfortably accommodate 2 adults."
        , "The room has been newly decorated, Plenty of space for luggage, desk space for work. moreover the staff was very coopervative and helped us throughout the stay",
        "Bright airy Studio apartment located on the Ground floor, a beautiful self-contained garden studio, located in the heart of historic Highgate Village.",
        "Bright airy Studio apartment located on the Ground floor, a beautiful self-contained garden studio, located in the heart of historic Highgate Village.",

    ]

    const openFilterHandler = () => {  // toggling the filter dropdown
        setOpenFilter(!openFilter)
    }

    const openPetsHandler = () => {   // toggline the pets dropdown
        setOpenPets(!openPets)
    }

    const openCoupleHandler = () => {  // toggling couple dropdown
        setCoupleToggle(!coupleToggle);
    }


    const petsFilter = () => {          // when the user click yes on dropdown this function gets triggerred thereby only showing me petsFriendly options and mutating the array

        let mutate = orignalArray.filter((item) => {
            return item.pets === true
        })

        setOriginalArray(mutate)
        setPetReviews(true);


    }

    const nonPetsHandler = () => {       // when the user clicks no on the dropdown this function gets triggerred and again returning the original array
        setOriginalArray(placeDetailsArray);
        setPetReviews(false);
    }

    const coupleFilter = () => {          // filtering couple friendly options
        let mutate = orignalArray.filter((item) => {
            return item.couple === true
        });

        setOriginalArray(mutate);
        setCo(true)

    }


    const noncoupleHandler = () => {
        setOriginalArray(placeDetailsArray);
        setCo(false)

    }


    const lowToHighFilter = () => { 
        const eitherSort = (arr = []) => {
            const sorter = (a, b) => {
                return +a.price - +b.price;
            };
            arr.sort(sorter);
        };
        eitherSort(placeDetailsArray);
        setOriginalArray(placeDetailsArray);
    }





    return (
        <div className='searchDeatilsMainParent'>
            {!coupleToggle && !openPets && <p className='text-2xl flex relative uppercase fof left-24 top-36'>Toatl {placeDetailsArray.length}  Stays in {loc}  </p>}

            <div className='functionalityButtonsHold cursor-pointer flex gap-4'>
                <img src={filterbtn} className="w-36 zoom" onClick={openFilterHandler} />

                <div className='flex coupleHold mt-3 zoom' onClick={openCoupleHandler}>
                    <img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/couple-3431093-2863604.png" className='w-12 pt-1 h-10 pl-2 inline-block' />
                    <p className=' inline-block pl-5'> Couple Friendly </p>
                </div>

                <div className='petHold mt-3 zoom' onClick={openPetsHandler}>
                    <MdOutlinePets className=' inline-block text-2xl pr-2' />
                    <p className=' inline-block'> Pet Friendly </p>

                </div>
            </div>

            {openFilter && <div className='dropdownFilter rounded-2xl capitalize'>
                <p className=" cursor-pointer pt-10 pr-4" onClick={lowToHighFilter} >  Low to high </p>
                <br />

                <div className='relative arrowsHold'>
                    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPh9c_dLqYXwYwXePJTwBAG8nTZG0V2LdAtA&usqp=CAU' className='h-4' />
                    <br />
                </div>


            </div>}

            {openPets && <div className='selectDropDown'>

                <div onClick={petsFilter} className=" pt-4 mb-8 cursor-pointer h-2 ">  Yes </div>
                <div onClick={nonPetsHandler} className="cursor-pointer h-2">No   </div>
            </div>}

            <div className='zindex'>
                {coupleToggle && <div className='selectDropDownCouple cursor-pointer'>
                    <div onClick={coupleFilter} className=" pt-4 mb-8 cursor-pointer h-2">  Yes </div>
                    <div onClick={noncoupleHandler} className="cursor-pointer h-2">No </div>
                </div>
                }
            </div>


            <div className=' topSearchLine absolute bg-slate-100'></div>




            {orignalArray.length > 0 && <div className='placeDetailsHold flex flex-col relative'>
                {orignalArray.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={item.id}>
                            <Link to={`/${item.id}`}>
                                <img src={item.homeMainPic} className="object-cover relative searchDetailsImage" />
                                <div className=' bifurcatingLine relative bg-slate-100'></div>

                                <div className='searchDatarevHold flex flex-col gap-1 relative'>
                                    <p className='fof text-md h-1'> {item.name} </p>
                                </div>

                                <p className=' inline-block relative text-xl mt-1 fof revSearchData'><AiFillStar className=' fill-red-400 pb-1 text-3xl inline-block' />  {item.stars} ({Math.floor(Math.random() * (999 - 100 + 1) + 100)}) </p>
                                <p className='SDPprice'> ${item.price}/ night </p>
                                {petReviewes && <p className=' inline-block petWlcHold'> <img src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/005/484/042/original/dog-logo-illustration-free-vector.jpg' className=' w-16 h-16 inline-block' />  Pets Are welcome </p>}
                                {co && <p className='coupleFriendlyHold relative'> <img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/couple-3431093-2863604.png" className='w-12 pt-1 h-10 pl-2 inline-block' /> Couple Friendly options </p>}
                            </Link>
                        </div>

                    )

                })}
            </div>
            }




            <div className='searchRevHold flex flex-col relative'>

                {reviewesArr.slice(0, orignalArray.length).map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={Math.random()}>
                            <p className=' text-gray-500'> "{item}" </p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchDetails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orignalArray` (notice you've left out an "i" in the name) should not be a state item, it should be computed from `placeDetailsArray` and the various filters, using `useMemo`.
Your code is rebuilding `orignalArray` from itself each time a filter setting changes. That is confusing.

Try something like:

```
const originalArray = React.useMemo(
  () => {
    const pass = (a) => a;
    const petFilter = (a) => a.pets === true;
    const coFilter = (a) => a.couple === true;
    const sorter = (a, b) => {
        return +a.price - +b.price;
    };

    const filteredResult = placeDetailsArray
      .filter(petReviews ? petFilter : pass)
      .filter(co ? coFilter : pass)
    ;

    return priceSort ? filteredResult.sort(sorter) : filteredResult;
  },
  [placeDetailsArray, petReviews, co, priceSort]
);
```

Comment: Right as you mentioned that i mistakenly was mutating the original array but the moment i started filtering the data out from "placeDetailsArray" instead of the "orignalArray" the code did start to work perfectly thank you so much :)